# como usar un formulario dentro de un modal con php?

Tags: php

tengo un modal y adentro de este modal tengo un formulario, el problema es que al darle guardar al formulario no se guarda en mi base de datos,pero si en ves de un modal uso otra pagina php mi formulario si funciona es decir si guarda,y no cambio nada del codigo , solo le cambio la forma de accerder.

les paso mi codigo

codigo para abrir el modal.esto funciona correctamente por que ya comprobe si la data se envia al modal

```
  $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('.egreso').click(function(){  
           var dni = $(this).attr("id");  
             $.ajax({  
                url:"condicion_egreso.php",  
                method:"post",  
                data:{dni:dni},  
                success:function(data){  
                    $('#employee_detail').html(data);  
                     $('#dataModal').modal("show");  
                }  
           });   




      });  
 });
```

codigo dentro del modal

```
<?php

   date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
setlocale( LC_TIME, 'spanish' );
   include '../conexionbd.php';
   include('funciones.php');

   $dni = $_POST['dni'];
   $consulta_alta ="SELECT cod_situacion,descripcion from situacion where cod_situacion>1";
   $resultado_consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_alta); 

   if (isset($_POST['btnguardar'])) 
  {
    $dni = $_POST['dni'];
    $encargado_egreso = $_POST['responsable'];
    $tipo_alta  = $_POST['tipo_alta'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $fecha_actual = date('Y-m-d');

    registrar_alta_paciente($conexion, $dni, $encargado_egreso, $tipo_alta, $descripcion,$fecha,$fecha_actual); 


  }

  ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ASPATPERU-SISBIO</title>


  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading text-center">
    <h3>
        CONDICION DE EGRESADO
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-body">
     <form action="" method="POST">
     <div class="form-group">
     <span>RESPONSABLE DE EGRESO</span>
     <input type="hidden" name="dni" value="<?php echo $dni; ?>">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="responsable" value="MEDICO GENERAL" >
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <span>TIPO DE ALTA</span>
     <select id="tipo_alta" name="tipo_alta" class="form-control">
        <?php
             while($fila_alta=$resultado_consulta->fetch_array())
              {
           ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $fila_alta['cod_situacion']; ?>"><?php echo $fila_alta['descripcion'];  ?></option>
 <?php
    }
    ?>
     </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <span>DESCRIPCION</span>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" type="text" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" >
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <span>FECHA</span>
     <input type="date" class="form-control" type="text" id="fecha" name="fecha">
     </div>
     <br>
     <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnguardar" name="btnguardar">Guardar</button>                      
                    </div>
       </div>


     </form>
  </div>    
  </div>  
  </body>
  </html>
```

codigo para guardar lo del formulario (registrar_alta_paciente) esta funcion se encuentra en un archivo php llamado funciones.php si pueden ver lo llamo al principio

```
  function registrar_alta_paciente($conexion, $dni, $encargado_egreso, $tipo_alta, $descripcion,$fecha,$fecha_actual)
  {


          $insertar_alta = "INSERT INTO alta_paciente(dni,responsable_alta,tipo_de_alta,fecha,descripcion,fecha_movimiento) VALUES ('$dni','$encargado_egreso','$tipo_alta','$fecha','$descripcion','$fecha_actual')";
          echo $insertar_alta;
          $resultado_insertar = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar_alta) or mysqli_error($conexion);




  }
```

Comment: Usa ajax para mandar la peticion del modal.

Comment: Tu código tiene un grave problema de seguridad. Te invito a que le eches un vistazo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php/53280#53280 para evitar ataques de inyección de código.

Answer (score 1):

Tiene razón Muriano, al incluir dentro del modal la comprobación if (isset($_POST['btnguardar']))  y la llamada a la función registrar_alta_paciente, esta comprobación y llamada no se llega a realizar cuando se realiza el POST desde el modal. Debes sacarlo fuera del mismo.
Este es un ejemplo muy sencillito de como debe funcionar la llamada al modal y como se debe recoger la respuesta desde fuera.

El código es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

if (isset($_POST["mail"]) ) {
    $mail=$_POST["mail"];
    $insertar_alta = "INSERT INTO mails(id,mail) VALUES (1,'$mail')";
    echo $insertar_alta;
    $resultado_insertar = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar_alta) or 
    mysqli_error($conexion); 
 }


?>

<div class="container">
<h2>Ejemplo Modal</h2>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <form name="new user" method="post" action="index.php"> 
        <input type="text" name="mail"/> <br />
        <input type="submit"  value="grabar"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que estás llamando a la función `registrar_alta_paciente` dentro del código que genera el formulario. Pero el formulario se carga en un modal por ajax y este código no esta presente cuando el formulario se recibe mediante post.

El código:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
setlocale( LC_TIME, 'spanish' );
include '../conexionbd.php';
include('funciones.php');

$dni = $_POST['dni'];
$consulta_alta ="SELECT cod_situacion,descripcion from situacion where cod_situacion>1";
$resultado_consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_alta); 

if (isset($_POST['btnguardar'])) {
    $dni = $_POST['dni'];
    $encargado_egreso = $_POST['responsable'];
    $tipo_alta  = $_POST['tipo_alta'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $fecha_actual = date('Y-m-d');

    registrar_alta_paciente($conexion, $dni, $encargado_egreso, $tipo_alta, $descripcion,$fecha,$fecha_actual); 


  }

?>
```

Debería estar en el script desde el que se llama al modal, o bien, en el script que figure en el `action` de tu formulario. Como en tu caso omites ese valor, el formulario se lanza contra el script cargado actualmente (repito, no contra el script que contiene el formulario)